# Show div on click, sliding down to much

Tags: jquery, html, css, onclick, slide

So, this is what I have so far:  [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/NHskg)

#### HTML

```
<div style="height:1000px;">
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<div id="p_img" style="height:300px;">
    <div target="p1" class="portfolio">1</div>
    <div target="p2" class="portfolio">2</div>
    <div target="p3" class="portfolio">3</div>
</div>
<div>
    <div id="p1" class="description"> <a class="close">x</a>
        AAA : Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the     industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </div>
    <div id="p2" class="description"> <a class="close">x</a>
        BBB : Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </div>
    <div id="p3" class="description"> <a class="close">x</a>
        CCC : Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </div>
</div>
```

#### JavaScript (jQuery)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".portfolio").click(function () {
        $('.description').slideUp();
        $('#' + $(this).attr('target')).slideDown();
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $('#' + $(this).attr('target')).offset().top
        }, 600);
    });
    $(".close").click(function () {
        $('.description').slideUp();
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $('#p_img').offset().top
        }, 600);
    });
});
```

#### CSS

```
.portfolio {
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:#ccc;
    margin:10px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.description {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    font-size:12px;
    display:none;
}
.close {
    float:left;
    padding:5px;
    background:red;
}
```

It's working pretty well, but there is a problem.

1. Click on the first grey box and details appear underneath it.
2. Scroll back up (do not click on the 'x' button) and click on the second grey box.

***Problem:***

You'll see that the page scrolls down too much and not to the top of the details of grey box 2.

***What it should do:***

When 1 is open and you click on 2, the page should scroll down to the to of the details of 2.

Comment: You forgot to post the link ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/NHskg/

Comment: sorry... It wasn't working in the original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just scroll to the parent div of all the target, and not the targets themselves.

like so

http://jsfiddle.net/NHskg/1/

I changed the animation to this

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('#targetWrapper').offset().top }, 600);
```

and gave an id the the parent div

```
<div id='targetWrapper'>
```

Comment: I need it to scroll down a little bit more. Is this possible in the code?

Comment: I fixed it myself by using the offset ;) I'm learning jquery step by step!:D

Comment: Could you add the extra function of making the details disappear when you click again on a item? So when you click it appears, when you scroll back up and click again on the same item the details disappear.. hope you can help.

Comment: Let me see what I can do :)

Comment: Here you go

http://jsfiddle.net/NHskg/2/  I added a check to see if it was visible, and changed it accordingly.